# Using bot framework with qna maker and sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework, chatbot

I wanted to create a chatbot for my website. The chatbot must  have an FAQ service, can assess users, can provide users with the link demanded and can enroll them in courses.
Now can I implement the FAQ part via QnAMaker and use sql server for other services like enrollment?
Can I use sql server and QnAMaker together?

Comment: you need to create your own qna maker and deploy it on azure. in your qna maker you can do whatever you want to do. like database driver with sql server and your own logic. create your bot and link with your qna maker with application id. build your bot based on your requirements.

Comment: Your questions is too broad. Could you select the parts you already tried to solve and add some description/example? E.g. "use sql server for other services like enrollment?" is really really broad subject

Comment: But I actually have to implement it cuz making this chatbot is my final year project. By enrollment I mean that the chatbot is able to enroll the user in courses. The course codes are stored in the database and the chatbot just have to make sure that the course code is valid and never selected before

Comment: But how can I do it can you kindly demonstrate Hasan Mehmood?

Comment: @Hafsah, did you create a BOT through Microsoft BOT Framework? [create a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) download the code and try to understand first.and when you tag my in comment please use @ and click on my name so that I can get notification.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me @Hasan Mahmood actually I am confused a lot as well I have to program the bot rather than creating it without  programming. And yes I have decided to make my bot using the bot framework with c# but I am not sure how to implement all these things altogether

Comment: Do let me know @Hasan Mehmood if you have any idea what to do

Comment: @Hafsah try to create a bot in azure and download code and run with bot emulator and try to understand the code. [create a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). [emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: @HasanMahmood is right. You are going to need to learn and do this. There _are_ lots of resources you can reference, including [blogs](https://blog.botframework.com/) and [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore). For SQL, treat this like any other project and integrate it in. As you build your bot, check that the question hasn't been asked already. If not, then ask specific questions, explain what you've tried, and provide code.

Comment: Thanks all for the help